# Eliminar/Juntar valores duplicados en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación y debo eliminar/juntar valores agregados dinamicamente a un objeto en JavaScript, el caso es, que debo agregar los valores más actualizados al objeto y no solo cualquiera.

```
var arreglo = [
        {"id":0,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}, // <- Este registro debe quedar eliminado, porque es antiguo
        {"id":1,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}, // <- Este registro debe quedar eliminado, porque es antiguo
        {"id":2,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-3","1","1","1","3"]}, // <- Este registro debe permanecer, porque es el mas actualizado
        {"id":3,"producto":["Cebollin"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}
    ]
```

He intentado con varios códigos pero no me lo actualiza, he intentado con un forEach y solo me da el primer valor y no el mas actualizado

```
var hash = {};
filteredCategories = arreglo.filter(function(current) 
        {
          let go = current.id !== undefined ? String(current.id) + String(current.producto) + String(current.productos_datos) : String(current.id);
          
          let exists = !hash[go] || false;
           
          hash[go] = true;
          
          return exists;
        });

filteredCategories.forEach(category => {
            if (!filteredCategories.find(cat => cat.id == category.id && cat.productos_datos == category.productos_datos)) {
                const { id, producto, productos_datos } = category;
                filteredCategories.push({ id, producto, productos_datos });
            }
        });
```

Partiendo del arreglo que deje aqui, pondre el resultado que estoy buscando:

```
var arreglo = [
        {"id":2,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-3","1","1","1","3"]},
        {"id":3,"producto":["Cebollin"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}
    ]
```

Como verán, solo hay dos productos y no hay repeticiones, los productos estan actualizados y es lo justo, eso es lo que busco, pero no logro resolverlo

Comment: Si necesitas "El más reciente" ¿ese no sería el registro de la última posición y ya?, algo como `arreglo[arreglo.length - 1]`. Si no es así por favor aclara más lo que necesitas

Comment: No, porque en esa lista puede haber diferentes productos con diferentes versiones, y necesito el mas actualizado de cada uno de ellos

Comment: Okey, para mayor claridad ¿podrías añadir a tu pregunta un ejemplo con el resultado esperado?

Comment: Listo bro, revisalo :)

Comment: Saludos. Te falta indicar el criterio como determinar cual es el mas reciente. En el ejemplo que pones (a simple vista) parece que es en base al `producto` el último que se encuentre en el arreglo.

Comment: Vale. La respuesta que pusiste esta correcta. Le tuve que quitar un poco de codigo porque la lista se actualizaba dinamicamente en un setInterval. Posteare el codigo final. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que la llave única que no se debe repetir es producto, con eso podemos usar un objeto para almacenar elementos en el y usar esa llave para eliminar cualquier elemento anterior, una vez utilizamos el objeto, recorremos el objeto creado y rearmamos los datos como esperas, así una propuesta para lo que necesitas sería lo siguiente:

```js
var arreglo = [
    {"id":0,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}, // <- Este registro debe quedar eliminado, porque es antiguo
    {"id":1,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}, // <- Este registro debe quedar eliminado, porque es antiguo
    {"id":2,"producto":["Tomate"],"productos_datos":["1-1-3","1","1","1","3"]}, // <- Este registro debe permanecer, porque es el mas actualizado
    {"id":3,"producto":["Cebollin"],"productos_datos":["1-1-1","1","1","1","1"]}
]

const products = {};

/* Eliminar elementos repetidos */

arreglo.forEach(element => {
    products[ element.producto[0] ] = element;
    delete element.producto;
});

/* Reconstruir como se espera */

const finalArray = [];

Object.entries(products)
    .forEach(([product, value]) => {
        finalArray.push({ ...value, producto: [product] });
    });

console.log(finalArray);
```